# Does anyone knows how to add 3 different texts every 10 rows using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Does anyone knows how to add 3 different texts every 10 rows?
I mean if i have 3 texts as example
comment1,
comment2,
comment3

and i need to divide 1000 rows into 30 rows , after the first 10 rows i need to add comment1, after 20 rows i want to add comment 2, and after 30 rows i want to add comment 3, then i need to reapeat the same in all 1000 rows. is there code enable me to do that in Notepad++??

Comment: Please stop adding the same question as "an answer" to other questions. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do the job.

**Note:** I've made an example that add 3 different comments after 2 lines, for your case, you have to change the `{2}` with `{10}`.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\A|\G)((?:^.+\R){2})((?:^.+\R){2})?((?:^.+\R){2})?`
- Replace with: `$1comment1\n(?2$2comment2\n)(?3$3comment3\n)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\A|\G)           # non capture group, beginning of file or restart from last match position
(                   # group 1
    (?:^.+\R){2}    # non capture group, a whole line, must appear twice (in your case, change that 2 with 10)
)                   # end group 1
(                   # group 2
    (?:^.+\R){2}    # non capture group, a whole line, must appear twice (in your case, change that 2 with 10)
)?                  # end group 2, optional
(                   # group 3
    (?:^.+\R){2}    # non capture group, a whole line, must appear twice (in your case, change that 2 with 10)
)?                  # end group 3, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1                  # content of group 1
comment1            # comment 1
\n                  # linefeed, you may use \r\n for windows end of line
(?2             # conditional, if group 2 exists
    $2              # content of group 2
    comment2        # comment 2
    \n              # linefeed
)               # end conditional
(?3             # conditional, if group 3 exists
    $3              # content of group 3
    comment3        # comment 3
    \n              # linefeed
)               # end conditional
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks alot, it works well, I appreciate your help and thanks again

Comment: @maagii: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)